# Filter Backbone collection into multiple lists

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to learn backbone.js and have been looking at todomvc to undestand it.

But there is something i'm wondering. If my todos has a category. How can i filter my collection and only display those categorized "work" or "private"?

By now i try something like this:

```
routes:{
        ":category":"list",
        ":category/:id":"todItem"
    },
```

How can i use the ":category" as a filter value?

Comment: I'd probably make it easier for yourself and have a route like: "/items/:category" and "/items/:category/:id". Just IMO.

Comment: Will the extra part "items" change anything? Or items return everything, and then category displays single category?

Comment: That'd be my URL design. "/items" displays all, "/items/:category" filters...

Comment: Would it be the same to have "" instead of "items"? if no path is defined show everyone?

Comment: Yeah, that'd be fine! Just saying I'd probably make the URLs a bit more explicit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method where of the collectioin to get an arry and then create a new collection with the returned elements

From the documentation:

> **collection.where**(attributes)  Return an array of all the models in a
>   collection that match the passed attributes. Useful for simple cases
>   of filter.
>
> var friends = new Backbone.Collection([   {name: "Athos",      job:
>   "Musketeer"},   {name: "Porthos",    job: "Musketeer"},   {name:
>   "Aramis",     job: "Musketeer"},   {name: "d'Artagnan", job: "Guard"},
>   ]);
>
> var musketeers = friends.where({job: "Musketeer"});
>
> alert(musketeers.length);

```
var newCollection = new Backbone.Collection(musketeers);
```